# remove whitespaces between and after brackets - in one regex (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Remove whitespaces between and after brackets.

Can this be written in one line (now I have two)?

```
function removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\s*\(\s*/gi, "(");
    str = str.replace(/\s*\)\s*/gi, ")");
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the white space before and after the parenthesis and the parenthesis itself using an or `([()])` in a group and use only the captured parenthesis in the replace.

In this example that would be group 2 `$2`

```js
function removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\s*)([()])(\s*)/gi, "$2");
}
console.log(removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets("adfdfdf ( fdf ) ljlkjljk"));
console.log(removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets("adfdfdf ( fdf ) ljlkjlj( (  (()) )  ))) (( (k"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the special replacement patterns of `replace` method, as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

```
function removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\s+([()])\s+/g, "$1");
    return str;
}
```

This will replace the whole regex match with the capturing group, which in this case includes only the parenthesis characters.

Here's an instant test:

```js
var regex = /\s+([()])\s+/g;
var input = "aaa a ( b bb b ) ccc c ( ddd";
console.log(input.replace(regex, "$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :-

```
function removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\s*\(\s*/gi|/\s*\)\s*/gi , "");
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I was surprised this would work with `|` outside of the `/.../` construct, and it turns out it doesn't ; you're just using the logical `|` "or" operator, which returns the first expression that evaluates to true, that is in your case the first pattern. Your code will replace spaces before brackets but never after.

Answer (score 0):

```
function removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\s*[\)|\(]\s*/gi, function(x){   
           return x.indexOf(')') > -1 ? ')' : '('; 
       });
    return str;
}
```

or ES6:

```
function removeSpaceAfterBeforeBrackets(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\s*[\)|\(]\s*/gi, x => x.indexOf(')') > -1 ? ')' : '(') 
    return str;
}
```